# Reading multiple variables from txt file in VB script

Tags: scripting, vbscript, windows-scripting, filesystemobject

I want to be able read in two variables at a time into a VBScript. What I'm doing is replacing certain text from a bunch of HTML files. I have a script already written to do this, but I have to input only one set of text at a time. Command line Example:

C:> replace.vbs (OldText) (NewText)

where (OldText) and (NewText) are both parameters.

```
strOldText = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
strNewText = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

Is there a way to have a text file set up like:

```
(OldText) (NewText)
(OldText) (NewText)
(OldText) (NewText)
(OldText) (NewText)
```

and have the script read one at a time?

My find and replace code works perfectly. I would just like to automate the script to read the parameters from the text file rather than me typing them in one at a time in command prompt.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If further information is needed please let me know. I hope it's clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use PowerShell for the whole thing instead of just to call the script, but I think this should work.  If not, the problem is probably in how I'm trying to call the vbscript in my example.

PowerShell:

```
Import-CSV textReplace.csv | % {
    wscript.exe replace.vbs $_.OldText $_.NewText
}
```

CSV content:

```
OldText,NewText
"String 1","String 2"
"String 3,"String 4"
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've never used that before, but it worked great!

Comment: Great to hear.  PowerShell is simple, flexible, and the scripting language that Microsoft has embraced now and for the foreseeable future.  Check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
strDelimiter = " "

strInfilePath = "C:\Path to file to read.txt"

Const ForReading = 1

Set objFso    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInfile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strInfilePath, ForReading)

Do While Not objInfile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine    = objInfile.ReadLine
    arrParts   = Split(strLine, strDelimiter)
    strOldText = arrParts(0)
    strNewText = arrParts(1)
Loop
```

Comment: Nilpo, This works also, I tried both answers just for fun. Thanks for the help!